# UIScrollView contentsize not displaying full content when using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView with many UIViews.Part of these UIViews are designed in storyboard and rest in code.So my autolayout constraints are in code as well as storyboard.Now the views that are applied constraints in storyboard are displayed perfectly i e scroll view's content size displays them properly..However for the UIViews that are designed in code, the content size of scroll view doesn't update.

This is how I am setting the content size of scroll view.

```
  -(void)setScrollViewContentSize{
//scroll view content size according to no of views.

CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *obj in self.eventScrollView.subviews) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, obj.frame);
}
self.eventScrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;

}
```

I apply the constraints as follows in code.

```
 UIView *submitView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 1051, 308, 30)];
    // set autolayout
submitView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[submitView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:submitView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:submitView.frame.size.height]];

[submitView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:submitView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:submitView.frame.size.width]];

 [self.eventScrollView addSubview:submitView];
```